# Tuck someone under one's wing

Tags: british-english, slang

To quote the sentence from Richard Templar's book *The Rules of Life*:

"My grandfarther had taken early retirement owing to an industrial accident and my grandmother worked in a large department store in London......I was too young for school and my grandfather wasn't to be trusted to look after me at home. Her (ie my grandmother's) solution was to ***tuck me under her wing*** - ***on some days physically as well as metaphorically***, as she smuggled me past managers and supervisors - and we went to work together."

My question is: What does it mean by "tuck someone under one's wing", in a metaphorical sense?

Note: The author is British.

Comment: This question can easily be answered by a simple search. See [under someone's wing(s)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+someone+under+someone's+wing)

Comment: I've voted to close this Q. on the grounds: "Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic."

Comment: It's a metaphor, based, eg, on the way that a mother hen will tuck her chicks under her wings to protect them and keep them warm.

Comment: See [The Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1203971/All-aboard-Mother-swan-takes-babies-wing-trip-pond.html) for picture of cygnets tucked under their mother's wing and also [BirdNote](http://birdnote.org/show/sungrebe-baby-board).

Comment: It means to take care of, in a loving fashion.

Comment: Note that the original saying (of a hen) was closer to "gathered [her chicks] under her wings," and that the predominant idiomatic wording today is "took [not _tucked_] [someone] under her [or his] wing."

Comment: This question is a better fit for our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks Guys for your kind explanations and letting me know about the sister site! Please delete the post!